# Allure Report, attached video not played

Tags: java, testng, allure

Using Java Bonigarcia WebDriverManager in docker for recording:

```
WebDriverManager
                .chromedriver()
                .enableRecording()
                .dockerRecordingOutput("recordings\chrome_25651151651.mp4")
                .browserInDocker();
```

Then on test fail trying to add this video to Allure using the following:

```
public class AllureTestLifecycleListener implements TestLifecycleListener {

    public void allureVid() {
       try {
           byte[] byteArr = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream("recordings\chrome_25651151651.mp4"));
           Allure.addAttachment("attachment name", "video/mp4", new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr), "mp4");
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTestStop(TestResult result) {
        if (Status.FAILED == result.getStatus() || Status.BROKEN == result.getStatus()) {
        allureVid();
        }
    }
}
```

But when report generated it looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFX6R.png)

I found out then this its happens because when the allure attach video file to report - the file is not yet ready, and really the size if attached file is less then the real video file locally.
The second thing I noticed that if I try to attach the existing file, that was created earlier - it works fine and video can be played.

How to add the video file to report when file ready? Or How to add the link to local file?